# fmt.Scanf en Go no funciona

Tags: go, sintaxis

Estaba aprendiendo Go en estos días a lo cual hice este pequeño programa aplicando las nociones básicas, pero el problema que me surgió es la entrada de datos, simplemente da lectura a la primera entrada de datos y la segunda entrada de datos toma el valor de la primera, por lo tanto no me deja agregar datos anexo el código del programa.

```
func main() {
var input int
var process string
var number int64
var f float32
for {
    //imprimo menu
    fmt.Println("Program for use a menu" +
        "\n1.- Factorial" +
        "\n2.- F to C" +
        "\n3.- Exit")
    //hago la primera entrada de datos la única que funciona
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &input)
    switch input {
    case 1:
        //si ingreso a esta opción la variable number tomara el valor de input no se porque
        fmt.Println("Factorial a number")
        fmt.Println("Input to number:")
        fmt.Scanf("%d", &number)
        fmt.Println(fact(number))
        break
    case 2:
        //si ingreso a esta opción la variable f tomara el valor de input al igual que el primer caso
        fmt.Println("F to C")
        fmt.Println("Input to F degrees:")
        fmt.Scanf("%g", &f)
        fmt.Println(ftoc(f))
        break
    default:
        tm.Clear()
        fmt.Println("this a valid option...")
        break
    }
    //instruccion para romper el ciclo
    fmt.Println("want to process (S/n):")
    fmt.Scanf("%s", &process)
    if process == "n" || process == "N" {
        break
    }
  }
}
```

Antes que nada muchas gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo qué (añadiendo cosas que faltan para que podamos probar el código):

- Trabajas bajo el `package main`
- Has importado el  `package fmt` que usas en el código

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)
```

- Querías sacar el factorial:

```
func fact(x int) int64 {
    var total int64 = 1
    for i := 1; i <= x; i += 1 {
        total *= int64(i)
    }
    return total
}
```

- Convertir de fahrenheit a celsius:

```
func ftoc(f float64) float64 {
    return (f - 32) * 5/9
}
```

- Cambiando el data type de la declaración de `number` a int (no creo que necesites sacar factorial de, por ejemplo, [9223372036854775807](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#int64)).
- Y eliminando `tm.Clear()`, no sé si te refieres a limpiar la terminal o hacer un `clear` pero no veo `package de eso`. Aún así podrías usar:

```
fmt.Print("\033[2J")
```

**Si ejecuto el código**:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var input int
    var process string
    var number int
    var f float32
    for {
        //imprimo menu
        fmt.Println("Program for use a menu" +
            "\n1.- Factorial" +
            "\n2.- F to C" +
            "\n3.- Exit")
        //hago la primera entrada de datos la única que funciona
        fmt.Scanf("%d", &input)
        switch input {
        case 1:
            //si ingreso a esta opción la variable number tomara el valor de input no se porque
            fmt.Println("Factorial a number")
            fmt.Println("Input to number:")
            fmt.Scanf("%d", &number)
            fmt.Println(fact(number))
            break
        case 2:
            //si ingreso a esta opción la variable f tomara el valor de input al igual que el primer caso
            fmt.Println("F to C")
            fmt.Println("Input to F degrees:")
            fmt.Scanf("%g", &f)
            fmt.Println(ftoc(f))
            break
        default:
            fmt.Println("this a valid option...")
            break
        }
        //instruccion para romper el ciclo
        fmt.Println("want to process (S/n):")
        fmt.Scanf("%s", &process)
        if process == "n" || process == "N" {
            break
        }
      }
    }

func fact(x int) int64 {
    var total int64 = 1
    for i := 1; i <= x; i += 1 {
        total *= int64(i)
    }
    return total
}

func ftoc(f float32) float32 {
    return (f - 32) * 5/9
}
```

**No veo que de problemas**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

En vez de poner `fmt.Scanf("%d", &anyVar)`, prueba añadiendo el caracter de salto de línea en tus líneas con `fmt.Scanf`, es decir, prueba esto: `fmt.Scanf("%d\n", &anyVar)`.